# ViewPager not loading Pages after the first time I navigate to the ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment that contains a ViewPager. When I navigate to this fragment I see the first page as expected. However, if I hit back, and then navigate to that fragment again, I am then presented with a blank white screen...

What I'm noticing in the Layout Inspector is that when I navigate to the ViewPager Fragment the second time, the ViewPager is present, but none of the page fragments are in the hierarchy.

Here is how I set up my viewPager in my ViewPagerFragment:

```
/**
 * Variables
 */

var pageOneFragment = ForgotPasswordInitiateFragment()
var pageTwoFragment = ForgotPasswordSubmitCodeFragment()
var pageThreeFragment = ForgotPasswordSubmitPasswordFragment()

lateinit var mViewPager: ForgotPasswordViewPager
lateinit var mPagerAdapter: ForgotPasswordPagerAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot_password_pager_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    forgotPasswordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(ForgotPasswordViewModel::class.java)

    pageOneFragment.viewPager = this
    pageTwoFragment.viewPager = this
    pageThreeFragment.viewPager = this
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    activity?.let {
        mPagerAdapter = ForgotPasswordPagerAdapter(it.supportFragmentManager)
    }
    mViewPager = viewPager
    mViewPager.adapter = mPagerAdapter
    mViewPager.setListeners()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}

inner class ForgotPasswordPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return pageOneFragment
            1 -> return pageTwoFragment
            2 -> return pageThreeFragment
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Pager position $position is out of bounds.")
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

I attempted to set all my `mViewPager` configurations into the `onResume` function but the same thing happened.

When does the viewPager actually populate its pages? Because what it seems like to me is they are populated the first time, but not the second....

EDIT:

I debugged the Activity's fragments on the back pressed and noticed that the pages were in that fragment stack, but not the actual viewPager fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
activity?.let {
    mPagerAdapter = ForgotPasswordPagerAdapter(it.supportFragmentManager)
}
```

I.e., using the activity's FragmentManager. That's always the wrong thing to do and the source of your issue. Instead, you need to use the Fragment's `childFragmentManager`:

```
mPagerAdapter = ForgotPasswordPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```